# Minimize/Maximize/Close buttons' tooltip and Devexpress lookAndFeel

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, tooltip

I'm trying to force Minimize/Maximize/Close buttons'  tooltips (in ribbonform) to get a look from a lookAndFeel. So far I created a ribbonform, then I placed defaultLookAndFeel component on it ahd I chose an OfficeBlue skin. My ribbon form changed however the tooltips for control buttons(minimize,maximize,close) look the same. I also tried to use DefaultToolTipControler however changing properties on appearance section didn't get any results.
Is there any way to change appearance of tooltips mentioned before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to get rid of the Aero integration.
Set `AllowFormGlass` to false.

Comment: Thanks this works :) Is it possible to aply this behaviour for all forms which are opened from ribbon ? Unfortunatelly XtraForm doesn't have a property AllowFromGlass

Comment: @george: `SkinManager.DisableFormSkins`.  http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressSkinsSkinManager_DisableFormSkinstopic

Comment: @SLaks DisableFormSkins restored the default control button(Vista like). However I wanted to make forms which I open from ribonform to have skinned buttons with skinned tooltips. Unforunatelly tooltips looks normal - windows vista style